# Intellisense for tensorflowjs in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc, tensorflow.js

The npm module @tensorflow/tfjs has declaration files, which have a comment structure like this:

````
/**
 * Creates a new array with randomized indicies to a given quantity.
 *
 * ```js
 * const randomTen = tf.util.createShuffledIndices(10);
 * console.log(randomTen);
 * ```
 *
 * @param number Quantity of how many shuffled indicies to create.
 */
/** @doc {heading: 'Util', namespace: 'util'} */
export declare function createShuffledIndices(n: number): Uint32Array;
````

which causes the intellisense of my vs-code to show something like this:

[image: undesired tooltip]

The documentation looks something like jsdoc, just closing and reopening the comment probably breaks it.

As it's extremely unlikely, that tensorflowjs has broken documentation, i am probably just making some very simple mistake. There is very likely a dupe for this. Sadly, all my searches failed.

Comment: `As it's extremely unlikely, that tensorflowjs has broken documentation` Every human makes errors 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> just closing and reopening the comment probably breaks it.

100%. It needs to be a single comment block.

Should be:

````
/**
 * Creates a new array with randomized indicies to a given quantity.
 *
 * ```js
 * const randomTen = tf.util.createShuffledIndices(10);
 * console.log(randomTen);
 * ```
 *
 * @param n Quantity of how many shuffled indicies to create.
 */
export declare function createShuffledIndices(n: number): Uint32Array;
````

Comment: Found open [issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2542) for this. Guess it's time for regex search&destroy, until it's fixed, and the new version is stable.

Comment: You might have noticed I fixed `@param number` (there is no parameter called number) to be `@param n` as well 

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed in tfjs 2.4.0, rejoice!